# Change the content of shinydashboard sidebars according to tabPanel selected

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinydashboardplus

I have the shiny app below with 3 different tabs, a sidebar and a right sidebar. I would like every time that I move to another tab the content of the two sidebars to change and display different widgets. In the commeted -out lines you can see the different widgets that I want to display.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shiny)


shinyApp(
  ui = tags$body(class="skin-blue sidebar-mini control-sidebar-open",dashboardPage(
    options = list(sidebarExpandOnHover = TRUE),
    header = dashboardHeader(title = "Investment Advisor Monitoring - Insider Trading",titleWidth = 450),
    
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(minified = F, collapsed = F,
                               h4("Investment Selected"),
                               textInput("StockTicker", "Enter Stock Symbol", value = "NFLX")
                               #textInput("StockTicker2", "Enter Stock Symbol 2", value = "NFLX")
                               #textInput("StockTicker3", "Enter Stock Symbol 3", value = "NFLX")
                               
                               ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      h3('Results'),
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Insider Training"),
        tabPanel("Switching"),
        tabPanel("Tax Loss Harvesting")
        
      )
      
    ),
    controlbar = dashboardControlbar(width = 300,
                                     h4("Insider Trading Parameters"),              
                                     
                                     
                                     selectInput("InsiderTradingModel", "Insider Trading Model",
                                                 c("Dynamic" = "Dynamic",
                                                   "AI based" = "AIbased"))
                                     #selectInput("InsiderTradingModel2", "Insider Trading Model 2",
                                      #           c("Dynamic" = "Dynamic",
                                       #            "AI based" = "AIbased"))
                                     #selectInput("InsiderTradingModel3", "Insider Trading Model 3",
                                     #           c("Dynamic" = "Dynamic",
                                     #            "AI based" = "AIbased"))
    ),
    title = "DashboardPage"
  )),
  server = function(input, output) { 
    
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

shinyApp(
  ui = tags$body(class="skin-blue sidebar-mini control-sidebar-open",dashboardPage(
    options = list(sidebarExpandOnHover = TRUE),
    header = dashboardHeader(title = "Investment Advisor Monitoring - Insider Trading",titleWidth = 450),
    
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(minified = F, collapsed = F,
                               h4("Investment Selected"),
                               uiOutput("mytab11"), uiOutput("mytab12")
                               
                               #textInput("StockTicker3", "Enter Stock Symbol 3", value = "AMZN")
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      h3('Results'),
      tabsetPanel(id = "tabs",
        tabPanel("InsiderTraining"),
        tabPanel("Switching"),
        tabPanel("Tax Loss Harvesting")
      )
    ),
    controlbar = dashboardControlbar(width = 300,
                                     h4("Insider Trading Parameters"),              
                                     uiOutput("mytab21"), uiOutput("mytab22")
                                     
                                     #selectInput("InsiderTradingModel3", "Insider Trading Model 3",
                                     #           c("Dynamic" = "Dynamic",
                                     #            "AI based" = "AIbased"))
    ),
    title = "DashboardPage"
  )),
  server = function(input, output) { 
    
    output$mytab11 <- renderUI({
      tagList(
        conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.tabs=="InsiderTraining"',
                         textInput("StockTicker", "Enter Stock Symbol", value = "NFLX"),
                         sliderInput('periods','Periods',min=1,max=120,value=60),
                         selectInput("mtvar", "Choose a variable", choices = colnames(mtcars))
        ))
    })
    output$mytab12 <- renderUI({
      tagList(
        conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.tabs=="Switching"',
                         textInput("StockTicker2", "Enter Stock Symbol", value = "APPL"),
                         selectInput("cvar", "Choose a variable", choices = colnames(cars))
        ))
    })      
    
    output$mytab21 <- renderUI({
      tagList(
        conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.tabs=="InsiderTraining"',
                         selectInput("InsiderTradingModel", "Insider Trading Model",
                                     c("Dynamic" = "Dynamic",
                                       "AI based" = "AIbased")),
                         #textInput("StockTicker", "Enter Stock Symbol", value = "NFLX"),
                         selectInput("ivar", "Choose a variable", choices = colnames(iris))
        ))
    })
    output$mytab22 <- renderUI({
      tagList(
        conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.tabs=="Switching"',
                         selectInput("InsiderTradingModel2", "Insider Trading Model 2",
                                     c("Dynamic" = "Dynamic",
                                       "BI based" = "BIbased")),
                         sliderInput('periodss','Periods',min=1,max=100,value=30),
                         selectInput("pvar", "Choose a variable", choices = colnames(pressure))
        ))
    })      
  }
)
```

Comment: I have created a similar Q based on your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69772735/display-controlbarmenu-in-right-sidebar-of-shiny-dashboard-based-on-tab-select

Comment: anotherr similar Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69813311/create-different-sidebars-for-tabsetpanel-nested-in-other-tabsetpanel-in-a-s

Answer (score 1):

It does not make sense to use `conditionalPanel`s nested in `renderUI` (as shown by @YBS). You should use one or the other.
I'd suggest only using `conditionalPanel` as it hides elements instead of re-rendering them, which is faster:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

shinyApp(
  ui = tags$body(
    class = "skin-blue sidebar-mini control-sidebar-open",
    dashboardPage(
      options = list(sidebarExpandOnHover = TRUE),
      header = dashboardHeader(title = "Investment Advisor Monitoring - Insider Trading", titleWidth = 450),
      sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
        minified = F,
        collapsed = F,
        h4("Investment Selected"),
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = 'input.tabs=="InsiderTraining"',
          textInput("StockTicker", "Enter Stock Symbol", value = "NFLX"),
          sliderInput(
            'periods',
            'Periods',
            min = 1,
            max = 120,
            value = 60
          ),
          selectInput("mtvar", "Choose a variable", choices = colnames(mtcars))
        ),
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = 'input.tabs=="Switching"',
          textInput("StockTicker2", "Enter Stock Symbol", value = "APPL"),
          selectInput("cvar", "Choose a variable", choices = colnames(cars))
        )
      ),
      body = dashboardBody(
        h3('Results'),
        tabsetPanel(
          id = "tabs",
          tabPanel("InsiderTraining"),
          tabPanel("Switching"),
          tabPanel("Tax Loss Harvesting")
        )
      ),
      controlbar = dashboardControlbar(
        width = 300,
        h4("Insider Trading Parameters"),
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = 'input.tabs=="InsiderTraining"',
          selectInput(
            "InsiderTradingModel",
            "Insider Trading Model",
            c("Dynamic" = "Dynamic",
              "AI based" = "AIbased")
          ),
          selectInput("ivar", "Choose a variable", choices = colnames(iris))
        ),
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = 'input.tabs=="Switching"',
          selectInput(
            "InsiderTradingModel2",
            "Insider Trading Model 2",
            c("Dynamic" = "Dynamic",
              "BI based" = "BIbased")
          ),
          sliderInput(
            'periodss',
            'Periods',
            min = 1,
            max = 100,
            value = 30
          ),
          selectInput("pvar", "Choose a variable", choices = colnames(pressure))
        )
      ),
      title = "DashboardPage"
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {}
)
```